# Extjs stateful grid. How to check if it's created for the first time?

Tags: extjs

I use 3 stateful grids that are replaced between each other in the same view. 2 of those grids simply extends first one. The only difference between grids is initial visibility of some columns. User can change this visibility in column menu and this setting stay like that because of *stateful* config.

Everything works good, when we consider only stateful part. But I don't know how to set initial visibility of columns. I tried like that

```
initComponent: function () {
    this.columnManager.getHeaderByDataIndex('firstIndex').setHidden(true);
    this.columnManager.getHeaderByDataIndex('secondIndex').setHidden(true);
}
```

and it works, columns are hidden when grid is opened for the first time and visible when user changes something and then open application once more. There is only 1 problem - in column menu they are always indicated as hidden which is clearly taken from my initComponent function. So I thought that maybe there is a way to check if grid has been ever shown or not. something like:

```
initComponent: function () {
    if (!this.getState()) {
        //hide given columns here
    }
}
```

but it doesn't work too, as state is always null.

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you do it in column config of the grid? Something like

```
Ext.create('Ext.grid.Panel', {
    title: 'Simpsons',
    store: Ext.data.StoreManager.lookup('simpsonsStore'),
    columns: [{
        text: 'Name',
        dataIndex: 'name'
    }, {
        text: 'Email',
        dataIndex: 'email',
        flex: 1
    }, {
        text: 'Phone',
        dataIndex: 'phone',
        hidden: true // <--- HERE
    }]
});
```

Comment: because as I said those 3 grids are practically identical. First one has more than 30 columns and 600 lines of code. I don't want to copy it all to edit true/false for few columns, so I simply extend first grid in other 2. But when I don't find a solution then I guess I will be made to copy everything.

Comment: Ok. Are the columns model the same for 3 grids or different? Do you call this.callParent() before this.getState() or after?

Comment: they all use 1 and the same model and store. I call callParent as first method in initComponent

Comment: May you provide some fiddle example?